# How to make webEnumerator.moveNext wait until executeQueryAsync query executes

Tags: javascript

I want executeQueryAsync to complete before giving back control to webEnumerator.moveNext, anyway ?

```
function onGetSubwebsSuccess(sender, args) {
    var webEnumerator = webCollection.getEnumerator();

    while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        alert("Loop 1");
        web = webEnumerator.get_current();
        this.props = web.get_allProperties();
        context.load(this.props);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
    }
}

function gotProperty() {
    var myPropBag = this.props;
    alert("Loop 2");
}
```

What's happening now is, I get   alert for "Loop 1" twice and then alert for "Loop 2" when it should be like this,

```
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 1
Loop 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Web properties ([Web.AllProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.allproperties%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) could be requested using a **single** query using the following syntax:

```
clientContext.load(webs,'Include(Url,AllProperties)');
```

you don't need to perform any subsequent asynchronous requests using  `executeQueryAsync` method to load web properties per every web.

The following example demonstrates how to load web properties from sub webs and save them into  `websProps` array:

```
(function(){
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var webs = ctx.get_web().get_webs();
  var websProps = {};
  ctx.load(webs,'Include(Url,AllProperties)');  //Note: Explicitly specify which properties to load for Web  
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       var e = webs.getEnumerator();
       while (e.moveNext()) {
          var web = e.get_current();
          var webUrl = web.get_url();
          var props = web.get_allProperties();
          var propNameValues = props.get_fieldValues();
          //save properties  
          //Note: For demonstration purposes vti_defaultlanguage property is saved, change it to your property name
          websProps[webUrl] = {'DefaultLanguage': propNameValues['vti_defaultlanguage']};
       }
       console.log(JSON.stringify(websProps)); 
    },
    function(sender, args){
        //Handle error
    }
  );
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the asynchronous behaviour of client object model.  If you want to wait till the code in executequeryasync completes then you can use Jquery deferreds.  Here is a nice article explaining how to use deferreds
http://scenicsharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/12/using-jquery-deferred-object-with.html?m=1

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method 'Deferred'

Comment: how can i apply in the example here please help i donot know how to make this work

Comment: Sorry,  I am on mobile and can't do much.  However,  make sure that you have added reference to JQUERY.  Deferreds are part of JQUERY

Comment: yes i have the jquery reference but its not working